# how can i know the number of visitors on the website?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

hello guys how are you i want just to know how can i calculate number of visitors for all pages not for one page for example i put this code in one page and this calculate number of visitor for the page i put it on not for all visitor on the all pages.

```
<?php 

$time=time();
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$timeout=$time-300;
$query1=mysql_query("delete from online where ip='$ip'")or die (mysql_error());
$query2=mysql_query("delete from online where time<$timeout")or die (mysql_error());
$query3=mysql_query("insert into online values('','$ip','$time')")or die (mysql_error());
$query4=mysql_query("select * from online ")or die (mysql_error());
echo $num=mysql_num_rows($query4);

?>
```

Comment: You could also use an external tool like Piwik: http://piwik.org/

Comment: Reading this gave me a strange twitch in my eye.

Answer (score 1):

Change `echo $num=mysql_num_rows($query4);` to

```
$num=mysql_num_rows($query4);
echo $num;
```

Please switch to mysqli and use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: thank you i have change it but i do not understand what is the related of the link you have gave me also my language English is not very good so i will not understand everything from php site

Comment: In some future version of php, mysql_query() and mysql_num_rows() [might stop working](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php). You need to [use different functions, starting now](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).